# 401 Unauthorized error in Express API post request

Tags: api, express, post, axios

I am trying to develop the logic for a POST route handler in Express. I put the following together:

```
const headers = {
  "Authorization":"TS Token asdfghjk-asdf-4567-fghjkl; tid=onfido-token";
  "content-type": "application/json"
};

const params = {
  "policy_request_id": "onfido_applicantandtoken"
};

app.get("/get_stuff", (req, res) => {
    axios
      .post("https://third/party/api", {
        headers,
        params
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        res.json(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        res.json("Error occured!");
      });
  }
});
```

I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized for the above. On Postman it works, but with the logic above I get a 401 Unauthorized, specifically in the logs I would get `Header 'Authorization' not found` or `Could not parse authorization header`. So I am unclear as to what could be going on with the header.

A lot of posts talk about `req.headers`, but my `req.headers` does not have the Authorization token and content-type in there, it has some other token that the API I am trying to connect to I assume needs to reach out to another API.

I have refactored it to look like this:

```
app.get("/get_stuff", (req, res) => {
    axios
      .post("https://third/party/api", params, headers)
      .then(function (response) {
        res.json(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        res.json("Error occured!");
      });
  }
});
```

And I am still getting the same exact error.

To be clear the params is not something that gets passed into the URL on Postman, but rather the body of the postman request.

Comment: You seem to be missing a double quote immediately after the word `Authorization` in your `headers` Object.

Comment: @esqew, that was a typo in putting this OP together. I wish it would have been this easy, unfortunately that was not it.

Comment: Secondly: aren’t your keys in the object you pass to `axios.post()`’s second argument supposed to be named explicitly? `{headers: headers, params: params}`, or similar? I’m genuinely curious as I remember there being a feature in ES6 that automatically infers the key names based on the variable you pass it but I can’t remember if that would be applicable in this situation.

Comment: @esqew, so with the above logic, the headers gets passed into a `config` object as a value of `data` like so `data: '{"Authorization": "TSToken asdfghjk-asdf-4567-fghjkl; tid=onfido-token"}` and `policy_request_id` becomes a property of `config` object with a value of `'onfido_applicantandsdktoken'`. Notice the headers object is being passed into the data property as a string? Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: You should refer back to [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for `axios.post()` as its second parameter is supposed to be  `data` (the body of the POST you’re trying to send) and would mean the behavior you just detailed in your comment above would be expected. 
The `headers` should be passed as part of the third parameter.

Comment: @esqew, yes I did do that and I have changed it to where its `axios.post("api/endpoint", params, headers)`. And now I get `data: '{"policy_request_id:"onfido_applicantandsdktoken"}'` and in `Authorization: "TS Token asdfghjk-asdf-4567-fghjkl; tid=onfido-token"` and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230241/discussion-between-daniel-and-esqew).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to successfully connect by declaring a global axios default like so:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
```

as documented here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#user-content-config-defaults